# SQL Compare previous order to current order by customer to compare Items

Tags: sql

I have a need for a query and I just cannot seem to make it work.

My data looks like:

```
╔══════════╦═════════╦═════════╦═══════╦════════════╗
║ OrderNum ║ Custnum ║  Items  ║ Units ║    Date    ║
╠══════════╬═════════╬═════════╬═══════╬════════════╣
║    15985 ║   75369 ║ Nuts    ║    12 ║ 02/15/2014 ║
║    15985 ║   75396 ║ Berries ║    14 ║ 02/15/2014 ║
║    65894 ║   75369 ║ Nuts    ║    10 ║ 03/23/2014 ║
║    65894 ║   75396 ║ Tarts   ║    14 ║ 03/23/2014 ║
║    95473 ║   75396 ║ Nuts    ║     3 ║ 06/01/2014 ║
║    95473 ║   75396 ║ Tarts   ║    19 ║ 06/01/2014 ║
║    95473 ║   75396 ║ Berries ║    19 ║ 06/01/2014 ║
╚══════════╩═════════╩═════════╩═══════╩════════════╝
```

And I need to report on hundreds of customers and about 25 Items.

What I am being asked to show is the Current Order, the highest order number, and compare it to last customer order.  Show the output from the query would be:

```
╔═════════╦═════════╦═══════╦═══════════════╗
║ Current ║ Current ║       ║               ║
║ Custnum ║  Items  ║ Units ║   Comments    ║
╠═════════╬═════════╬═══════╬═══════════════╣
║   75396 ║ Nuts    ║     3 ║ Decreased(-7) ║
║   75396 ║ Tarts   ║     5 ║ Increase(5)   ║
║   75396 ║ Berries ║    19 ║ New           ║
╚═════════╩═════════╩═══════╩═══════════════╝
```

And if the Units are the same from previous to current the comment would be "No Change".

I have not been able to create a query that will just pulls the current order and the previous order for comparison.  I have tried `MAX(Date)`, `MAX(ORDERNUM)`......

I have extensive Excel and limit Access background and cannot find an answer in my head or on the forums. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Most recent query looked like:

```
Select CustNum ,OrderNum ,Items ,Units 
   ,Case Date > (Select MAX(Date) - 2 From TABLE)
   Then Date
   End
From TABLE

Where CustNum IN (
    etc.....
 )
```

With this query I did receive ALL orders by customer and Items with Units.

Comment: what database are you using?

Comment: and what code did you write looked the closest - please edit your post with example code

Comment: Using SQL Server 2008

Comment: Did you post the correct data sample? Why the Units of item Tarts is 5? And there are two custome numbers in an order, is it correct?

Comment: I guess the item Tarts' Units should be 19 and comments should be 'Increase(5)', that make sense.

Comment: Yes Jaugar, I miss typed that.  Should be 5.

Comment: I think there all the custome number should be 75396 instead of 75369.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
with last2_orders as (
  select * 
  from (
    select dense_rank() over(partition by custnum order by ordernum desc) as orderseq, orders.*
    from orders) as temp 
  where orderseq <=2
),
last_orders as(
  select * 
  from last2_orders
  where orderseq = 1),
prior_orders as (
  select *
  from last2_orders
  where orderseq = 2),
temp as (
  select
    last_orders.custnum,
    last_orders.items,
    last_orders.units,
    last_orders.units - coalesce(prior_orders.units, 0) as changes
  from last_orders
  left join prior_orders
  on last_orders.custnum = prior_orders.custnum
    and last_orders.items = prior_orders.items)
select 
  temp.*,
  case 
    when changes>0 and changes<> units 
      then 'Decreased('+convert(varchar,changes)+')' 
    when changes>0 and changes = units 
      then 'New' 
    when changes<0 then 'Increase('+convert(varchar,changes)+')' 
    else 'No Change'
  end as comment
from temp
```

1. First temporary table get last 2 orders of all custome by using
   dens_rank function.
2. Then you can join last_orders and prior_orders
   with custome number and item name to get the differnce between last two orders.

Result:

```
CUSTNUM   ITEMS     UNITS   CHANGES     COMMENT
75396     Nuts      3       -7        Increase(-7)
75396     Tarts     19      5         Decreased(5)
75396     Berries   19      19        New
```

Here is the [Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f0eba/26). You should add more customer's data and test it.

Comment: Jaugar, This is truly incredible.  Works like a charm.  Thank you for the assistance.  I have some studying to do "get" query.

Answer (score 0):

You need query like this (writing from head, so can contain syntax errors, mysql syntax):

```
select q2.CustNum, q2.Items, q2.Units as LastOrderUnits, ifnull((
    select Units
    from table as b
    where b.CustNum=q2.CustNum and b.Items=q2.Items and b.OrderNum<q1.maxOrderNum
    order by b.OrderNum desc
    limit 1
), 0) as prevOrderUnits
from
(
    select CustNum, max(OrderNum) as maxOrderNum
    from table
    group by CustNum
) as q1
inner join
table as q2
on (q1.CustNum = q2.CustNum and q1.maxOrderNum = q2.OrderNum)
```

this query will provide you with information about last order quantities and previous order quantities, you can modify it further to get output you need by using `if..then...`